# How to use two event loops in python application

Tags: python, rpc, pyzmq

Let's say that I have a class that is using zmq to pass messages in and out.
And I want to control it with RPC to make a remote facade for it.

How can I do that?

```
class Processor()

def init()
state = AddHeaderState() # There is more states of course
zmq_sender = create_zmq_sender()

def set_state(state):
...

def process(message):
output = state.process(message)
zmq_sender.send(output)
```

So with that example lets say that I want to change states remotely.

If I would add zerorpc to that I wouldn't be able to use zmq to pass message in and out and vice verca, right?
Is my question more clear with this example?

Comment: do you know [this](http://zerorpc.dotcloud.com/)?

Comment: I've read the documentation. So what?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zerorpc/_LdFqXI76rU

Comment: Well it's an RPC based on ZMQ the docs explain how to use it with lots of grate examples. So can you narrow the question?

Comment: I've added some pseudo-code, maybe that would help you help me.

Comment: What are the two loops you mention in the title?

Comment: Event loops. I'm sorry that I didn't mentioned that.

Comment: And suddenly no one is answering...

Answer (score 0):

Am I right to assume that you want to run two sending channels side-by-side/concurrently? There is a whole [section in zguide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc45) devoted to multi-threading. I found the *taskwork2: Parallel task worker with kill signalling* example in the *Handling Errors and ETERM* section useful.

If I assumed wrong you might want to clarify with a drawing. PlantUML lets you do that. [On my Github](https://github.com/lusitania/keep-it-simple/tree/master/online-sync#init-commandchannel) is an example for a flow-control with ZMQ in mind.